# How similar are Unix and Linux exactly?

Tags: linux, unix, gnu

I am a computer science minor and I do appreciate *nix a lot more since i started to delve into computer science. I used to be a windows fan boy and now i own two macs (as well as my PC which has windows and ubuntu on it).

I want to learn more about how linux was developed. I know that linux is only the kernel and the GNU is actually the most of what i am interfacing with. So when i type `ls -al` on my mac which uses unix how is it different from when i type `ls -al` on my Ubuntu boot on my PC? Does the difference actually lie in the differences between linux and unix? Or does unix use a non-GNU libraries for stuff like `ls` and `cd`?

So what exactly are the difference of linux and unix? Does Unix use GNU libraries for `ls`, `cd`, and all those common terminal operations?

Comment: I would imagine that you would get better answers to this question if you posted over on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Most of the differences between versions winds down to the BSD <--> sys5 fork. (shm, sessions, ttys) most of this has converged since then. (mostly caused by linux and POSIX) BTW: I would advise you to read APUE before asking this question. (and maybe Bach, first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to know that ... **L**inux **I**s **N**ot **U**ni**X**. :)

Good question, but it's difficult to give a straight answer.
The kernel is different. The design is different. The software is different (!)

That said, if you have Mac OS X (UNIX), you can build almost any command-line tool that was written for Linux.
Most of the free open-source software is compatible with both Linux ans UNIX, so depending on your level, you might never know the difference.

But technically, there's a huge difference. If you're on a hardware and driver-level you will start noticing differences, but if you're above those levels, you can easily write portable code.

Some people would claim that Linux is the poor-man's UNIX (which is probably also true), while others would say that Linux fixes the problems that UNIX has.

Due to the nature of the question (it's fairly broad), it's difficult to go in details.
I work with both and do not feel a huge difference. My UNIX was set up for me, so I'm basically a novice user there, but I had to install and configure parts of my Linux system myself.
I would say (in my own opinion) that most of the time, Linux is something you build yourself, you decide which components you want. UNIX on the other hand is a little more "one big package", though you can still add components.

Looking at it from a different angle: Linux is open-source and free, where some versions of UNIX aren't. UNIX is often found in enterprise servers from large companies.

Take a command like 'ls' as you mentioned. Older versions of UNIX had a command called 'lc' which listed directories instead of files (as far as I recall). This command does not exist in the UNIX that Mac OS X is based upon, so there's a difference between UNIX and UNIX.
On the other hand, Linux did not make a straight copy of the UNIX command 'ls'. The output often differ slightly, and the switches are different. But!
If you're running Bash, then Bash on your Mac OS X is most likely exactly the same Bash you've got on Linux, just the version differ.
If you got 'curl' on your Mac, and 'curl' on Linux, then it *IS* the same tool, because it's built from the same sources; it's just built for two different Operating Systems.
GCC is the same as well. (**G**NU is **N**ot **U**nix - but it works well on UNIX).

If you install the gitolite server (which I'm quite fond of), you will experience that it will not install on the stock Mac OS X 10.5.8; this is because the arguments for the 'cp' command differ. The author refused to correct the problem, when I suggested him a solution that would work on all platforms. So 'cp' may not always be 100% compatible, and I do not know whether or not it would be a good idea to 'upgrade', because the 'cp' that you have now is compatible with the scripts that Apple provided with your system. Upgrading 'cp' to a different version could break compatibility, which could mean that your system got corrupted and would need a re-install. -So it's better to not upgrade that particular command. ;)

Comment: BTW: OS X is a BSD ripp-off. Just saying...

Comment: I have no problem with you saying that. ;) As far as I remember, it's strongly connected to FreeBSD.